# Sentence Stress: I'm sort of busy right now

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, american-accent, word-stress

I heard this phrase in a TV show: "I'm sort of busy right now". You can listen it here (I cut out the phrase): https://clyp.it/4khla44l

Phonetically  it looks like: [ɑɪm soərt əv bɪzi raɪt naʊ]. The words "sort" and "of" can be linked together, because of the consonant + vowel. But this is not what I'm interested in.

I can hear some stress on the word "sort" and "busy". I think "busy" gets the most stress when pronounced. Am I right? But what about the ending words "right now"? It seems to me they don't get any stress, or there is little stress on the word "now".

I would be grateful for any suggestion! Thank you.

Comment: It would be unusual for the speaker to place any significant stress on *sort of*. This could only imply that he's not *very* busy, and that he intends (or is willing to be persuaded) to discount that factor and help the other person as requested. And placing stress on *right now* would only be appropriate if the speaker wishes to convey the subtext that he *will* be willing to help at some future time, but *not right now*. Surely this is how stress/emphasis works in *all* languages?

Answer (score 2):

The emphasis indicates the crucial part of the sentence.  You could put the emphasis in lots of different places, depending on what you want to .... ***emphasize.***

> ***I'm*** sort of busy right now"

I am busy, but perhaps I know of another person who could help you.

> I'm ***sort of*** busy right now.

I am a little bit busy, but I might be able to help you if it won't take very long, or you can convince me it is super important.

> I'm sort of ***busy*** right now.

I am busy.  With light stress, this is the default way one might pronounce the sentence.
With heavy stress, it might mean: *Although I said I am **sort of** busy, I am actually **very** busy.*

Maybe even:  *You are treating me as if I am not busy, but you should be able to tell that I am.*

> I'm sort of busy right ***now.***

I am busy now, but I might have time to help you later, if you can wait for a little while.

Comment: The classic movie/TV use of heavy stress on busy - the hero is fighting for his life, his cell phone rings, and it's somebody with a fairly trivial question. The conflict between the triviality of the caller and the understatement of "busy" are an action/comedy cliché.